# Scala: Any predefined function to iterate over list(0), then list(0, 1), then list(0, 1, 2), etc.?

Tags: scala

I want to iterate over a scala list in an incremental way, i.e. the first pass should yield the head, the second the first 2 elements, the next the first 3, etc...

I can code this myself as a recursive function, but does a pre-existing function exist for this in the standard library?

Comment: Depending on what you're going to do with those sublists, you may be looking for scanLeft...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `.inits` method to get there, albeit there may be performance issues for a large list (I haven't played around with making this lazy):

```
scala> val data = List(0,1,2,3,4)
data: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> data.inits.toList.reverse.flatten
res2: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: `.inits` returns an iterator so should be OK with large lists.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Yeah, I thought `.inits` itself would be OK, but wondered about performance issues of following that with `.toList` - does that build up the resulting list of lists lazily?

Comment: Sure. the. toList will exhaust the iterator. But since in your example you're flattening the whole lot anyway, doesn't really matter :)

Comment: No, it doesn't build the resulting list lazily (and if it did, the list couldn't be _reversed_ without forcing it).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `take` like so:

```
 scala> val myList = 1 to 10 toList
 myList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

 scala> for(cnt <- myList.indices) yield myList.take(cnt+1)

 res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[List[Int]] = Vector(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

Comment: This just isn't good. Why do you need indicies? `for (cnt <- 1 to myList.length)` does the job if you for some reason don't want the predefiend `inits`.  It doesn't give the predefined function the OP wanted, and doesn't allow incremental iteration.

Comment: @ TheArchetypalPaul, `.inits` is fine for iterating over the entire List. Performance wise, it is faster. My answer bordered on the predefined `take` which is nice if you don't wan to go through the entire list. I used `indices` as I was going through the entire list anyway.

Comment: The chance the OP didn't know about `take` is, er,  low. That wasn't the predefined function they were looking for, I'll bet. And your use of indicies still doesn''t make sense to me. Whatever, I'm out.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Why do you think `indices` (defined as `0 until length`) is worse than `1 to length`? While this doesn't provide incremental iteration, you can fix this by using `myList.indices.iterator` instead.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul No, it doesn't create an array. It creates a `Range`, as I've said, and as you can see by looking at the type.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction. OK, so this one is reasonablt. I'll remove some comments and reverse my downvote

Answer (score 1):

OK, since I've whined enough, here's an iterator version that tries reasonably hard to not waste space or compute more than is needed at at one point:

```
  class stini[A](xs: List[A]) extends Iterator[List[A]] {
    var ys: List[A] = Nil
    var remaining = xs

    def hasNext = remaining.nonEmpty
    def next = {
      val e = remaining.head
      remaining = remaining.tail
      ys = e :: ys
      ys.reverse
    }
  }

  val it = new stini(List(1, 2, 3, 4))

  it.toList
  //> List[List[Int]] = 
  //      List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `for((x, i) <- l.view.zipWithIndex) println(l.take(i + 1))`

if you need something side-effected (I just did `println` to give you an example)

Comment: Or with `yield` if you don't want to have something without a side effect: `for ((x, i) <- l.view.zipWithIndex) yield l.take(i + 1)`

Comment: Why do this when `.inits` exists? It's just slower and unclear.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Because `inits` gives you the result in the reverse order, so to get the desired order you need to do `inits.toList.reverse` which is also slow.

Comment: What's wrong with  `for (i <- 0 until l.length) yield l.take(i+1)`? Adding the index only to take it away again is just messing about for no reason. And the `.view` doesn't do anything useful since it will get completely evaluated anyway.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Nothing wrong with that. If you'd already have a list, and you'd want sublists with only the first element, then the first two elements, etc. then mfirry's solution (but with `yield`) would be good.

Comment: @jesper, i feel you're still missing the point. My alternativ yields (pun intended) exactly the same results, only it doesn't pointlessly use view and zipWithIndex. They add nothing (other than complexity and slowness) to the solution.  Both are a way of  defining i as 1... length in turn and them passing that to `take`.

Comment: Since you don't use `x`, there is no point in `zipWithIndex`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov,  it's "needed" as a roundabout way of defining a list of indicies (not really needed, I agree, but that is its function here)