# Scala Sequence to a Sequence of Sequence

Tags: scala

I have a Sequence as:

```
Seq(1,2,3)
```

I'm trying to get a Sequence of a Sequence that would look like this:

```
Seq(Seq(1), Seq(1,2), Seq(1,2,3))
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
  def pop(acc: Seq[Seq[Int]], elems: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = elems match {
    case Nil => acc.flatten
    case x :: xs =>
      pop(acc ++ Seq(Seq(x, xs.head)), xs.tail)
  }
```

As expected, I'm hitting a NoSuchElementException on the place where I do xs.head. I'm sure there must be something that I"m doing wrong! May be I'm missing. This one does not give me the expected result, but this was just a try!

Edit: The original goal was to split a String that comes in as:

"1.2.3" to a Sequence of Strings as Seq("1), Seq("1.2"), Seq("1.2.3")

To achieve this, I'm first splitting based on the . character, going over the resulting Sequence and concatenating them again with the . character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Any predefined function to iterate over list(0), then list(0, 1), then list(0, 1, 2), etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691530/scala-any-predefined-function-to-iterate-over-list0-then-list0-1-then-li)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there:

```
  def pop(acc: Seq[Seq[Int]], elems: Seq[Int]): Seq[Seq[Int]] = elems match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs =>
      if (acc.isEmpty)
        pop(Seq(Seq(x)), xs)
      else
        pop(acc ++ Seq(acc.last ++ Seq(x)), xs)
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 Seq(1,2,3).scanLeft(Seq[Int]())(_ :+ _).tail
```

If the list is longer, appending to the end of a `Seq` in `scanLeft` might become too expensive. In that case you could prepend to a List, and add a reverse step, or use some mutable builder (like `ListBuffer`).

Answer (score 5):

You can also achieve this (not too efficiently, but concisely) using `inits`:

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3).inits.toList.reverse.tail
res0: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3))
```

**EDIT**:
Per question update, a similar way to find all prefixes of a String up to a "." delimiter would be to just treat the String as a sequence of Chars:

```
"1.2.3".inits.filter(s => s.nonEmpty && !s.endsWith(".")).toList.reverse
```

Comment: Cool! Why is that in efficient?

Comment: it traverses the input twice - once to create `inits` result and once to reverse it. Of course this is only significant for large lists, for short ones this is negligible.

Comment: I guess I like this as in my Seq, I will never ever have more than 3 elements!

Comment: Glad to have helped! although I must admit I find @Landei's solution (using `scanLeft`) more elegant, wish I'd have thought of it myself :)

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my question again? I have edited it now!

Comment: added, there's probably a more elegant solution to that too, but I can't thing of one...

Comment: `I guess I like this as in my Seq, I will never ever have more than 3 elements! ` - consider a 3-tuple then. `def f[A](xs: (A, A, A)): List[List[A]] = {
     |     val (a,b,c) = xs
     |     List( List(a), List(a,b), List(a,b,c))
     | }`

Answer (score 4):

```
val input = Seq(1,2,3)
val result = (1 to input.length).map(input.take).toList // List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: +1, and another variant in the same spirit using `indices` : `input.indices.map(i => input.take(i + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

If your `Seq` does not have duplicates and is ordered, you can do:

```
val yourSeq = Seq(1,2,3)
yourSeq.map(e => Seq(yourSeq.takeWhile(_ <= e))).flatten
```